# Identify and replace duplicates elements from a vector

Tags: r

I have got a vector which is as under

```
a<- c(1,1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,4,1,1)
```

Here we can see  that there are lot of duplicate elements, ie. they are repeated ones.
I want a code which can replace all the elements which are consecutive and duplicate by 0 except for the first element. The result which i require is

```
a<- c(1,0,0,2,3,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,4,0,1,0)
```

I've tried

```
unique(a)
       #which gives
[1] 1 2 3 0 4
```

Comment: have you tried `duplicated` as well?

Comment: `rle` function will help to identify repeated elements and then you can replace them by `0`'s

Comment: yeah i've tried duplicate function too. it either removes all the duplicate or replaces all the duplicate by 0. I want only consecutive elements if they are duplicate should be replace by 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can created a lagged series and compare

```
> a
 [1] 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 4 1 1
> ifelse(a == c(a[1]-1,a[(1:length(a)-1)]) , 0 , a)
 [1] 1 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
replace(a, duplicated(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(a))))), 0)
# [1] 1 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0 1 0
```