# Replace duplicate values in vector using criteria from other columns in data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, duplicates

I have a very similar problem to: 
[Identify and replace duplicates elements from a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121135/identify-and-replace-duplicates-elements-from-a-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I need to replace duplicate values in a column occurring in a sequence BUT based on criteria from other columns in the data frame.

I have a data frame like this (plus a number of extra columns):

```
 ID<- c("1V","1V","1V","1V","2V","2V","4V","4V","4V","4V","4V")
 year<- c(1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
 sequence<- c(1,2,2,1, 1,2,1,2,1,1,1)
 score <- c(5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,11,11,11)
 examp <- data.frame(ID,year, sequence, score)

> examp
   ID year sequence score
1  1V    1        1     5
2  1V    1        2     5
3  1V    1        2     5
4  1V    2        1     5
5  2V    1        1    10
6  2V    1        2    10
7  4V    2        1    10
8  4V    2        2    10
9  4V    3        1    11
10 4V    3        1    11
11 4V    3        1    11
```

What I need is to replace the duplicate scores within each ID, year and sequence with NA. Also the sequence couple with the score should be replaced with NA. Thus, no rows are deleted, only specific entries.

```
> examp
   ID year sequence score
1  1V    1        1     5
2  1V    1        2     5
3  1V    1        NA    NA
4  1V    2        2     5
5  2V    1        1    10
6  2V    1        2    10
7  4V    2        1    10
8  4V    2        2    10
9  4V    3        1    11
10 4V    3        NA   NA
11 4V    3        NA   NA
```

All rows are retained. The same scores may occur across different IDs/years/sequences, but only within each unique combination of these three columns can I replace a duplicate score.

Example with a single vector and solution from the other linked question:

```
 a <- 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 4 1 1
 ifelse(a == c(a[1]-1,a[(1:length(a)-1)]) , 0 , a)
 [1] 1 0 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0 1 0
```

I am unsure of how to adapt the above code in the question above with multiple criteria. Is it possible?
Primarily, the most important is to replace the scores, but if someone has a solution to replacing both scores and sequence I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use subsetting and `is.na`.

```
is.na(examp[duplicated(examp[1:3]), c("sequence", "score")]) <- TRUE

examp
   ID year sequence score
1  1V    1        1     5
2  1V    1        2     5
3  1V    1       NA    NA
4  1V    2        1     5
5  2V    1        1    10
6  2V    1        2    10
7  4V    2        1    10
8  4V    2        2    10
9  4V    3        1    11
10 4V    3       NA    NA
11 4V    3       NA    NA
```

Here, `ID year sequence` returns a logical vector the length of your data.frame that signals whether the rows of the first three variables are duplicates of previous rows. `c("sequence", "score")` determines the columns that are to be replaced. Then `is.na` is set to TRUE in those column for the duplicated rows.

A longer, but more readable version is to use the variable names rather than their positions.

```
is.na(examp[duplicated(examp[c("ID", "year", "sequence")]), c("sequence", "score")]) <- TRUE
```

This is also safer in the long run in case the positions shift due to merging or other manipulations. It may be also easier to read/interpret when reviewing the code six months from now.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(examp)`), grouped by 'ID', 'year', we get the row index (`.I`) where column 'sequence', is `duplicated` and then `set` those values in the dataset columns 'sequence', 'score' to NA.  This should be very efficient as we are setting in place

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(examp)[, .I[duplicated(sequence)], .(ID, year)]$V1
 for(j in 3:4){
   set(examp, i = i1, j=j, value = NA)
 }

examp
#    ID year sequence score
# 1: 1V    1        1     5
# 2: 1V    1        2     5
# 3: 1V    1       NA    NA
# 4: 1V    2        1     5
# 5: 2V    1        1    10
# 6: 2V    1        2    10
# 7: 4V    2        1    10
# 8: 4V    2        2    10
# 9: 4V    3        1    11
#10: 4V    3       NA    NA
#11: 4V    3       NA    NA
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
examp %>%
  group_by(ID, year) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., duplicated(.), NA)))
```

---

With `base R`, we can do a compact option

```
examp[duplicated(examp[1:3]), 3:4] <- NA
examp
#   ID year sequence score
#1  1V    1        1     5
#2  1V    1        2     5
#3  1V    1       NA    NA
#4  1V    2        1     5
#5  2V    1        1    10
#6  2V    1        2    10
#7  4V    2        1    10
#8  4V    2        2    10
#9  4V    3        1    11
#10 4V    3       NA    NA
#11 4V    3       NA    NA
```

Or another option is `replace` with `lapply`

```
examp[3:4] <- lapply(examp[3:4], function(x) replace(x, duplicated(examp[1:3]), NA))
```